# what s problem to give one-to-may and many-to-one relationship .why this error is occure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: blooom.utility.model.BlooomModules.serverModel
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1904)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    ... 60 common frames omitted

Comment: please put your source code to question

Comment: i cant do that ..@HienNguyen

Comment: You Can add more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard this is a good way to ask questions. And kindly refer this guide, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your problem without the code in question.
Maybe you interchanged the annotations in your model classes?

As the exception says you can only annotate a `Collection` with `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany` or `@CollectionOfElements`.

Have a look at the examples here:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your type field by Collection as this example:

```
@OneToMany
private Article article;
```

replace by

```
@OnToMany
private Collection<Article> article;
```

Answer (score 0):

That error occurred because I give reference to model class without using any collection class.
 error code :
        private XYZModel xyzmodel;
 Correct Code:
       private Set xyzmodel = new HashSet();